# phantomjs-pdf not work

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, sails.js, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using phantomjs-pdf in my sailsjs app. This code working fine in my local machine(ubuntu 14.0). but server machine(ubuntu 12.0) cause error, like below

```
  internal/child_process.js:274                                                                                                                      
      var err = this._handle.spawn(options);                                                                                                           
                                 ^                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    TypeError: Bad argument                                                                                                                            
        at TypeError (native)                                                                                                                          
        at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:274:26)                                                                                       
        at exports.spawn (child_process.js:339:9)                                                                                                      
        at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:141:15)                                                                                           
        at /var/www/test/node_modules/phantomjs-pdf/lib/phantomjs-pdf.js:83:16                                                           
        at /var/www/test/node_modules/phantomjs-pdf/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:721:13                                               
        at /var/www/test/node_modules/phantomjs-pdf/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16                                                
        at /var/www/test/node_modules/phantomjs-pdf/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:269:32                                               
        at /var/www/test/node_modules/phantomjs-pdf/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16                                                
        at /var/www/test/node_modules/phantomjs-pdf/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:17                                               
        at /var/www/test/node_modules/phantomjs-pdf/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37                                               
        at async.series.paperFormat (/var/www/test/node_modules/phantomjs-pdf/lib/phantomjs-pdf.js:51:70)                                
        at /var/www/test/node_modules/phantomjs-pdf/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:713:13                                               
        at Immediate.iterate [as _onImmediate] (/var/www/test/node_modules/phantomjs-pdf/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)         
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:371:17)
```

This is my error. Any one tell me what is the problem. help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall all NPM packages and then reinstall NPM packages.